# JavaFX execute start(Stage stage) again during app execution

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am Fabio.

I am coding a theater's seats booking application in JavaFX. I have  128 circle as seats as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEo7H.jpg), occupied are red, free are green, and the one selected by user is orange.

When the user click on "Prenota" button I store in a mySQL database the chosen seat is now occupied, so next time I will open the app it will be red, instead of green.

The theater is done through a Pane, so is it possible to refresh or reload the entire  **public void start(Stage stage)** to show the new seats without closing the app?

Thanks everyone.

PS: My start function is like:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
Group mainGroup= new Group(costoCliente,prenota,calcolaTotale,textMessaggi, //so on//);         

Scene mainScene= new Scene(mainGroup,903,950);
mainScene.setFill(Paint.valueOf(configXML.parametriStile.coloreSfondo));
stage.setTitle("Theater Booking");
stage.setScene(mainScene);
stage.show();
}
```

Comment: You want to reload the entire application because one piece of data changed...??? I suggest you redesign your application.

Comment: I prefer a void function setRed(int number) in class Seat, but I don't know how to select that seats.  pane.getChildren().add(seat); -> is the code to add a seat to a Pane, so I can't access a single seat. @James_D

Comment: Seriously, if there is no way to update the individual data you need, and have the view respond accordingly, you really need to redesign the way you have the app structured (at least the way you have the data modeled). You should probably read up on MVC/MVP design, if you are not familiar with it, and use that kind of application structure.

Comment: You know how my Pane theater function works, so could I work there as you have done with reservedProperty? @James_D

Answer (score 0):

In the Prenota button controller, after you store the data, you can use the FXMLLoader class. 
Something like:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new
FXMLLoader();   
loader.setLocation(Aplicacion.class.getResource("MainView.fxml"));
mainLayout = loader.load();          
Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I updated my question including a sample of my function start. I am not using FXML, so I'm looking for something easier